# Razor MVC unclosed tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, tags

For some reason, I cant close li tag, I added comment which li tag is in question inside code

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.kategorije) {
    <li>
        <a href="/category/@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Name)/@item.CategoryID">@item.Name</a> @if (item.ChildCategory.Count > 0) { foreach (var child in item.ChildCategory) {
        <li class="child">
            <a href="/category/@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(child.Name)/@child.CategoryID">@child.Name</a>
        </li>
        } }
    </li>
    <!-- it says this tag has no matching start tag -->
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possibly because the inner `<li>` element is not contained in a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops, found it, I needed to nest child list elements into new ul, basic html mistake

```
<ul>
                    @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.kategorije)
                    {
                        <li>

                            <a href="/category/@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Name)/@item.CategoryID">@item.Name</a>


                            if (item.ChildCategory.Count > 0)
                            {  <ul>
                                foreach (var child in item.ChildCategory)
                                {
                                <li class="child">
                                    <a href="/category/@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(child.Name)/@child.CategoryID">@child.Name</a>
                                </li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                            }
                        </li>

                    }
                </ul>
```